# Why Runtime doesn't start another process?

Tags: java

I thought it should print the message multiple times, but only once? What's the problem? Thanks.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class RestartApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {       
        System.out.println("Test restarting the application!");       
        restart();
    }

    private static void restart() {
        try{
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java RestartApplication");
        }catch(IOException ie){
                   ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I would print what exception is being thrown. Don't ever leave empty catch blocks.

Comment: Stop ignoring exceptions, and you will discover why. Note that this would be an innovative way of bringing a machine to its knees.

Comment: So, now that you've printed the stack trace, what does it say? Have you at least taken some time to read the message and try to understand it?

Comment: I added the exception, but nothing changes. No exception thrown. Just print once.

Comment: No exception was thrown, so no trace message. Thanks.

Comment: OK. Now that's a stranger problem than I thought. Sorry for jumping to conclusions before actually testing by myself.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it only prints once is that you need to print the output from the process, otherwise it will run silently:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java RestartApplication no-run");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String line = null;
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(line);
}
```

When the output is displayed you will see a chain of processes each starting a new copy of `RestartApplication` which will consume a lot resources so you may wish to consider to pass in a command-line argument **not** to start another process.

Even a simple argument check will save your system by restricting the # of processes to 2:

```
if (args.length == 0) {
   restart();
}
```

Comment: yes, it print multiple times. Is it possible to terminate the previous process immediately it's done and start a new process? It consumes lots of resources probably because all the processes co-exist?

Comment: A 'cleaner' approach would be to signal a forward check here. See update.

Comment: What do you mean by cleaner approach? After i added the process.destroy() line, after a short while, i still get "ould not reserve enough space for object heap". Why is that?

Comment: `process.destroy()` won't terminate so-called grandchildren processes so this approach is not reliable.

Comment: At the end of restart(), i added System.exit(0). Shouldn't it kill the current JVM? But i got the same no enough space problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect running this doesn't work on the command line so its not going to work when you run it from Java either.

```
System.out.println("Test restarting the application!");
Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"java", "-cp", System.getProperty("java.class.path"), "RestartApplication"});
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(exec.getInputStream()));
for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; )
    System.out.println(line);
```

prints

```
Test restarting the application!
Test restarting the application!
Test restarting the application!
Test restarting the application!
Test restarting the application!
Test restarting the application!
Test restarting the application!
Test restarting the application!
Test restarting the application!
Test restarting the application!
Test restarting the application!
Test restarting the application!
Test restarting the application!
Test restarting the application!
Test restarting the application!
Test restarting the application!
Test restarting the application!
Test restarting the application!
Test restarting the application!
Test restarting the application!
Test restarting the application!
```

Comment: I tired it in eclipse, it's the same.